# elasticsearch: return matched part of document

Tags: elasticsearch

I am almost certain this should have been asked and answered elsewhere but no matter how much Googling I do I can't find a similar answer. Quite likely I'm doing it wrong but worth asking.

I want to be able to do a query in Elasticsearch and return the elements that contain the results or at least mark the elements within the document.

Say I have a document:

`{
 "_id": 1,
 "name": "The hare and the turtle",
 "author": "Some guy",
 "chapters": {
     "1": {
        "title": "The race",
        "body": "The hare and the turtle lined up before the wall, where there was a Macbook.."
     },
     "2": {
        "title": "The hare pulls ahead",
        "body": "After the starting gun the race begins. The Macbook appears again."
     },
     "3": {
        "title": "No references to Apples",
        "body": "Nothing about Apples here"
     }
}`

I then want to query (either in the document, or in the whole index) for the keyword "Macbook" but I want to know what chapters that keyword or query appeared rather than the whole document containing a match as is the usual returned value. How would I do this?

I know of the highlight functionality in Elasticsearch which will by default put a html tag around the match but in this case what I really am after is the chapter numbers and content below of the matches. I don't care about chapter 3 and its content as it does not contain "Macbook".

How can this be achieved in ES?

Comment: Expected output would be something like (notice lack of chapter 3);

`"chapters": {
     "1": {
        "title": "The race",
        "body": "The hare and the turtle lined up before the wall, where there was a Macbook.."
     },
     "2": {
        "title": "The hare pulls ahead",
        "body": "After the starting gun the race begins. The Macbook appears again."
     },
}`

Comment: Was this ever resolved? I'd be interested in seeing your solution.

Comment: Nested objects is what you need to achieve this. Sorry should have updated the question - https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/nested-objects.html